# iOS 10.1 (full release version) not compatible with the latest version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, compatibility

I need to use IOS 10.1 full release version to run an app I am building. How do I make the latest version of Xcode (version 8.1) work with IOS 10.1 full release version?

Comment: There's no XCode 8.1 on offer at the moment - I'm sure there will be an update that will address this. I'm in exactly the same boat.

Comment: I am in this boat all day.

Comment: I don't see what problem you're having. I am using Xcode 8.1 (released yesterday) to build and run on a device running iOS 10.1 (released yesterday). They go together.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8.1 is only at Gold Master at the moment. You'll have to wait for the "full" release of 8.1 which will be available on App Store, until then you have to use 8.0 to archive your projects.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW this [gist](https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d) offers a work around by symlinking to the Beta version of Xcode.

Copied for reference:

```
// The trick is to link the DeviceSupport folder from the beta to the stable version.

ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.1\ \(14B54\)/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

// Then restart Xcode and recommect your devices. You will need to do that for every beta of iOS 10.1+/Xcode 8.

// sudo needed if you run the Mac App Store version. Always download the dmg instead... you'll thank me later :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xcode 8.1 beta 3 to build on iOS 10.1 devices here:
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09212016a